# FlatList is not scrolling or scrollable with multiple items

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist, scrollable

I am using FlatList for list of video tiles but somehow it is not scrollable can someone please give an input what is wrong in here ?

```
const TileList = styled(FlatList)({ overflow: 'hidden' }, variant({
    prop: 'orientation',
    variants: {
        vertical: {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            flexGrow: 0,
            maxHeight: '40%',
        },
        horizontal: {
            width: 250,
            //height: '100%',
            maxWidth: 250,
            flex: 0,
        }
    }
}));



              <TileList
                testID="teams-other-list"
                data={remainingTiles}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                contentContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                horizontal={isHorizontal}
                inverted
                orientation={orientation}
                initialScrollIndex={0}
            />
```

Comment: Im trying to get your code working in [snack](https://snack.expo.dev) and Im not familiar with styled-components. Could you post where variant is coming from?

Comment: Variant is basically orientation either it is vertical or horizontal which is passed as orientation prop.  "  orientation={orientation}. "

Answer (score 1):

It's not scrollable because of overflow 'hidden' style option. It hides everything outside the component's frame. Remove it and the scroll will appear

Comment: it helped thanks but that does not work in iOs, it is now scrollable in android which is super weird

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `initialScrollIndex` prop, `getItemLayout` prop is required. Or the flatlist is not scrolled.

Check this out:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex